# How to convert XML from Latin-2 to UTF-8 in Android/C#/Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, encoding, xamarin

I have a problem. In my app i download XML file from the Web. Its encoding is ISO-8859-2. I put some data from this XML to Spinner and there are **questions marks** instead of some **polish characters**. Have I to change encoding to UTF-8 to solve that problem? If yes, how to do it? I tried using method found on the Internet but it doesn't help

```
private XmlDocument ChangeXmlEncoding(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string newEncoding)
    {
        if (xmlDoc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
        {
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = (XmlDeclaration)xmlDoc.FirstChild;
            xmlDeclaration.Encoding = newEncoding;
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }

public static string GetPageAsString(System.Uri address)  
    {  
        string result = "";  

        // Create the web request  
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;  

        // Get response  
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
        {  
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  


            // Read the whole contents and return as a string  
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();  
        }  

        return result;  
    }
```

and **usage**:

```
                System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml");
                XMLString = GetPageAsString(uri);
                dokument = new XmlDocument ();
                dokument.LoadXml(XMLString);
                dokument = ChangeXmlEncoding(dokument,"utf-8");
```

Comment: I suspect your `GetPageAsString` method is losing information. We can't tell as we can't see that. Fetch the *binary* data instead - or use a method which loads the XML directly from the URL. (Ideally, use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument, tooo.)

Comment: I added code of this method to my question. In previous version of my app I used XmlDocument's Constructor which took url as a parameter but it didn't work, there were weird bugs. Could you help me with editing GetPageAsString() in way to solve my problem with encoding?

Comment: "there were weird bugs" really doesn't describe what's wrong at all. (Not that `XmlDocument` has such a constructor...) Your current code assumes that the response is in UTF-8 (as you haven't specified an encoding for the StreamReader). At the very least you could use `XmlDocument.Load(Stream)` to avoid having to do the decoding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetPageAsString` method is broken, basically - it's *assuming* that the encoding is UTF-8, as that's what `StreamReader` uses by default.

I would strongly urge you to avoid performing the string decoding yourself. In order of preference (best first), I would:

- Use LINQ to XML and `XDocument.Load(uri.ToString())`
- Use `XmlDocument.Load(uri.ToString())`
- Use `XmlDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())` in a method to just load the XML instead of loading the content as a string

In all of these cases, the XML parser will handle decoding the text from the binary data.